# Como filtrar la ultima entrada registrada por su user id - Django

Tags: django, sql, update, filtro

Hola amigos soy nuevo en django. Quisiera hacer una consulta para actualizar el campo number.

Lo que quiero hacer es filtrar por el usuario y filtrar por la ultima entrada de ese usuario, para despues actualizar el campo number.

Los querysets que conozco son los siguientes, pero no se como podría implementarlos para realizar la consulta:

```
Model.objects.latest('x')
Model.objects.filter()
```

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

**models.py**

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

Con el class Meta me ordena los registros por el mas reciente, pero ahora como podria acceder al ultimo registro para actualizarlo.

Muchas gracias amigos!

Comment: Para tu caso puedes apoyarte del método [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) quedando de la forma `Model.objects.first()` y eso te retorna el último resultado (dado tu orden) es decir, el más reciente y puedes cambiar el campo `number`

Comment: Funciona excelente German, Con ese ya accedo ala ultima query de ese usuario, pero ahora como podría acceder al campo number?

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer pero seria suficiente algo como esto: `getattr(Model.objects.first(), 'number', 0)` o `Model.objects.first().number`

Comment: Gracias German si funciona, saludos hermano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que quieres filtrar por el id de usuario:

```
instance = Model.objects.filter(user__id=5).first()
```

o por el primer nombre del usuario:

```
instance = Model.objects.filter(user__first_name='Pedro').first()
```

o por el apellido:

```
instance = Model.objects.filter(user__last_name='Torres').first()
```

Por la forma en que tienes tu ordering se usa `first()`, si quitaras esa condición de ordering deberías emplear `last()`. Con esto ya podrás editar el valor de number con `instance.number = numero_flotante`  y guardarlo con `instance.save()`

Answer (score 1):

EL resultado de todos los objetos ordenados por fecha se guarda en una lista, puedes acceder al primer elemento el cual debería ser el que tiene la fecha más reciente:  `ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0]`  o pudises acceder no solo al último sino a los 4 0 5 últimos, ejemplo  `ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0:4]` ,  `ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0:5]`

Comment: Que tal @Leandro L, he intentado tu recomendación `ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0]` y funciona excelente, pero po ejemplo cuando quiero acceder a más del primer elemento `ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0:3]` me muestra el siguiente ERROR: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'number'` tienes alguna idea del porque podría ser el problema viejo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos, que bueno q funcione algo, cuando guardas en una variable varios objetos ejemplo <code>ultimo = Model.objects.all()[0:3]</code>, ultimo deja de ser un objeto y se convierte en una lista de objetos, por eso no tiene el atributo 'numbre', debes hacer un recorrido por cada uno de ellos, algo asi: <code> for value in ultimo: print value.number </code>

Comment: del modo que te expliqu'e ahora recorrerias los objetos que stan guardados dinamicamente con el ciclo for, ahora si deseas hacerlo estatico, para el primero ser'ia [0:3][0], para el segundo [0:3][1], y para el tercero [0:3][2], de este modo si puedes decir ultimo.number